# How to redefine \eqref output, keeping numbering but changing text and brackets?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I am looking for a macro to redefine \eqref{} output.

Resulting in:
*(equation: 1.1)*

Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be italics, *including the parentheses*? Please confirm.

Comment: Can be also without italics. I'd like to figure how to remove parentheses from original numbering (1.1) and wrap them around entire reference.

Comment: With `cleveref`, you have `\cref{label}` resulting in something like `equation (1.1)`.

Answer (score 4):

in `amsmath`, `\eqref` is defined like this:

```
\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
```

since `\ref` is at the root of this, you can redefine it as

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{(equation: \ref{#1#})}
```

this will forgo the upright form of parentheses and number, which are
intentional (and traditional) stylistic features.

Comment: A tie is missing, I believe.

Comment: @egreg -- well, i'd put a tie there, but not everyone does.  (i certainly wouldn't use italic for the digits or punctuation either.  chacun à son goût.)